# In SQS + Lambda, can I write the distributed processing logic of Lambda internal poller that reads messages from SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-sqs-fifo

I am currently using **SQS(fifo) + Lambda trigger architecture**.
Whenever a message is issued to SQS, a Lambda function is created and processed by the internal poller.

This is perfectly normal, typical SQS + Lambda processing logic.
But I want to limit the maximum number of Lambdas created per second.
No matter how hundreds of thousands of messages are delivered to SQS, the Lambda internal poller rate-limits these messages to create a Lambda function, **and I want to write this rate limiting logic myself.**

Is it possible? If possible, I would appreciate it if you could leave any related materials!
Also, **if you have a better recommended architecture than SQS + Lambda**, please share!

Comment: You can sill write your own SQS consumer (on EC2 or ECS) and process on your own pace.  I prefer SQS+Lambda too for its simplicity (even it is not possible to change the polling parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I want to limit the maximum number of Lambdas created per second.

You do this by setting [concurrency limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html) of your lambda. If you only want one function, set it to 1.

> and I want to write this rate limiting logic myself.

You can't change internal logic of a lambda's SQS pooler.